# How to evalute this limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $A_N$ defined as follow:

$$A_N=\prod_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac{\alpha n+\nu}{\beta n+\mu}.$$

Calculate:

$$\ell=\lim_{N\to\infty}A_N.$$

P.S. This not a homework. I just thought about it and I tried to calculate it but I find no way. I tried to apply the $\log\left(\dotsc\right)$ function and I find my self going in circle.

Comment: Note that for $n$ large, $(an+b)/(cn+d)$ is close to $a/c$, and the product can't converge unless $a/c=1$. That should get you started.

Comment: If $a/c\leq 1$ the product still can't converge?

Comment: It can diverge to zero.

Comment: Yes. That means $A_N$ converges to zero. Am I right?

Comment: No, it means $A_N$ diverges to zero. That's the terminology used with infinite products. Take logs and get an infinite series going to minus infinity. Since we don't say a series converges to minus infinity, we don't say an infinite product converges to zero.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. I did not know that.

Comment: It appears that the only case when $\ell\ne0$ and $\ell\ne\infty$ is when $(\alpha,\nu)=(\beta,\mu)$. Can you prove this yourself (following @Gerry's indications)?

Comment: (Answering your comment to the answer already posted) You MUST have made some progress following @Gerry's hint... For example, what happens when $\alpha\ne\beta$?

Comment: If $\alpha>\beta$ then $A_N \rightarrow \infty$ otherwise $A_N \rightarrow \ell$ where $\ell$ is finite number that I do not know its value. Am I right?

Comment: If $\alpha\gt\beta$, yes you are right. If $\beta\gt\alpha$, what did you say was happening, already?

Comment: The thing is I did not find the $\ell$ yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha=\beta=0$ then $A_N=(\mu/\nu)^N$ hence the asymptotics are obvious. If $A_N$ converges to a nonzero finite limit $\ell$ then $A_{N-1}\to\ell$ hence
$$
\frac{\alpha+\nu/N}{\beta+\mu/N}=\frac{A_N}{A_{N-1}}\to1.
$$
The LHS converges to $\alpha/\beta$ hence the only case when $A_N$ converges to a nonzero finite limit  $\ell$ is when $\alpha=\beta\ne0$. (And a moment of thought reveals that if $|\alpha|\gt|\beta|$ then $|A_N|\to\infty$ while if $|\beta|\gt|\alpha|$ then $A_N\to0$.)

From now on, assume without loss of generality that $\alpha=\beta=1$. Then,
$$
\log A_N-\log A_{N-1}=\log\left(\frac{1+\nu/N}{1+\mu/N}\right)=\frac{\nu-\mu}N+o\left(\frac1N\right).
$$
If $\nu\ne\mu$, the RHS is not summable hence $\log A_N\to+\infty$ (if $\nu\gt\mu$) or $\log A_N\to-\infty$ (if $\nu\lt\mu$), that is, respectively $A_N\to+\infty$ or $A_N\to0$.
Finally:

> The only case when $A_N\to\ell$ with $\ell$ finite and nonzero is when $\alpha=\beta$ and $\nu=\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** This product can be re-written as $A_N=\bigg(\dfrac\alpha\beta\bigg)^N\cdot\dfrac{\bigg(\dfrac\mu\beta\bigg)!\cdot\bigg(N+\dfrac\nu\alpha\bigg)!}{\bigg(\dfrac\nu\alpha\bigg)!\cdot\bigg(N+\dfrac\mu\beta\bigg)!}$ , whose convergence can then be studied using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: What is $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: This is the long, hard way...

Comment: @Did: No, not particularly.

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: @Did Can you please show me the easy way ? Thank you.